# Visa requirement for Chinese passport holder going from Shenzhen to Hong Kong

Tags: visas, hong-kong, chinese-citizens

We are a group of 6 people from Malaysia, going to Shenzhen (2 days) then train to Hong Kong (4 days) and ferry to Macau (2 days), then back to Malaysia. All hotels are booked with booking.com.

The problem is that one person in our group is a Chinese passport holder with a valid Malaysia visa. Going to Shenzhen is ok but from Shenzhen to Hong Kong, we don't know if she needs a visa to enter Hong Kong since we are going to stay there for 4 nights. (7-day visa free applicable?). We will take a ferry to Macau (7-day visa free applicable to enter Macau on transit to Malaysia) for another 2 nights, then flying off to Malaysia.

Does anybody know this visa rule?

Comment: See the closely related question [Do Chinese citizens require a visa to go to Hong Kong for less than 7 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24377/do-chinese-citizens-require-a-visa-to-go-to-hong-kong-for-less-than-7-days?rq=1), including an email reply from the Hong Kong immigration authorities. It sounds like they're pretty responsive to questions, if you want to email them with this specific question to have an official response you can show.